# SwiftUI, not all lines of my Text get presented

Tags: swiftui

I wondered why me SwiftUI Text don't get presented, or at least not all of him... Here Is a picture: [image]

I mean I typed 12 Times "Long Text", and only 10 get presented... No idea why. I tried `.lineLimit(nil)` too.

Thanks, Boothosh

Comment: Please post code, not images of code.

Comment: Set .layoutPriority(1) or set fixedSize()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `.lineLimit(nil)`, use `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)`.

```
Text("Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, ")
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

Result:

[image: Text does not cut off]